# Rapidly print objects from array, then cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm new to JavaScript, but have had experience with other programming languages.

I'm having a hard time designing a simple task in JavaScript:

Given an array of letters, I want to randomly select 9 letters that will rapidly print one after another. Then, I want to display two random letters that a user will select left or right (to select which occurred more recently in the list). Then after selection, pick another random 9 letters.

I'm at a loss on how to make the letters print rapidly instead of all together...? I also want this to run 10 times. Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

This is what I have so far:

```
var stimuli = new Array('B','C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H')
var num_trials = 10; 

function trials() {
    while (num_trials > 1) {

        //fills array with random letters
        var random = new Array()
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            //randomly picks 9 
            random[i] =  stimuli[Math.floor(Math.random() * stimuli.length)]
        }

        //from "random" array,displays stimuli
        for (var i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
            document.write(random[i]);

        }

        document.write("<br>");

        //randomly picks two letters from random array to display
        document.write(random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)]+ " , ")
        document.write(random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)])


        //user selects, left, right or up

        num_trails--; 


    }
}
```

Comment: There is probably a jQuery plugin for that :P Seriously though, why ask for a jQuery solution?

Comment: `document.write()` shouldn't be used in interactive code.

Comment: _...I'm at a loss on how to make the letters print rapidly instead of all together...?_  This seems to be the core of your question, but it's not clear exactly what you mean.  Could you describe the current vs the desired behavior in more detail?

Comment: @Waxen I think they mean with a delay, so first letter, wait,. second letter.

Comment: @PM 77-1 what's an alternate way I could print the values without document.write()...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the letters one by one, you'll have to use either `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. I'd use `setInterval`, replace your current for loop with:

```
var i = 0;
var printer = window.setInterval(function(){
  if (i < random.length) {
    document.write(random[i]);
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(printer);
    /* Here goes the rest of your code after the for loop, eg.
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)]+ " , ");
   etc. */
    return;
  }
  i++;
}, 300);
```

The above code should print each letter in turn.

When `i >= random.length`, it will run all of your other code, after the for loop (the for loop has exited).

Comment: I also want the letter to disappear after writing them? How could I do this?

Comment: what I want is for the letters to print, then disappear after being printed but document.body.innerHTML = ''; clears the entire document. The above code also only prints them one after the other with the previous letter still being there.

Comment: @gg4 You'll have to store the entire on-screen content in a variable, and reset it to that after each document.write.